# AngularJS - Variables in Layout to swap login/my account sections

Tags: angularjs

Just getting into AngularJS coming from a Zend Framework 2/jQuery way of working.

My layout.html within Zend Framework would contain something like:

```
<html><body>
<div id="topNavigation" class="nav nav-fixed">
<?php
if ($this->identity()) :
    ?>
    <button id="logoutBtn">Log out</button>
    ?>
else:
    ?>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
    <?php
<?php
endif;
?>
</div>
<?php 
// The content from each ViewAction
echo $this->content 
?>
<footer>This is the common footer text.</footer>
</body></html>
```

Now I'm converting this to AngularJS I understand the index.html is the layout with ngView directive pointing to template files for each view.
How do I get variables into my layout to switch logged in state? If you can't really control the layout, where do I hold the code that maintains logged in state, cause I don't see anywhere for global code.

My angularJS index.html layout file is currently like the above:

```
<html><body>
<div id="topNavigation" class="nav nav-fixed">
    <button id="logoutBtn">Log out</button>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button>Login</button>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>
<footer>This is the common footer text.</footer>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place is probably in $rootScope which, since all controller's scopes inherit from this, can be thought of as 'global'.

I see in your index.html above, though, you haven't specified a controller.  You would need to add a controller (probably in 'body'), and in that controller, add the login info to the $rootScope.

Once you have a variable in your $rootScope (say 'isLoggedIn'), then you can use the ng-show and ng-hide directives to determine what subsets of the DOM you want displayed.

Comment: ah sorry, I didn't add the controller thing. I thought the ngView was where your controller's template loaded. So there isn't anywhere global to put stuff like this and you just reference $rootScope in every controller. ok, cool! thanks :)

Comment: Any element in your HTML can have a controller, which comes in pretty handy.  If there's another controller defined in a child of those elements, then that controller will inherit from its parent.